# INSERT/UPDATE conditional split in SSIS working incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, ssis, conditional-statements

I looked for an answer for my specific issue before posting. Didn't find anything. I have a conditional split in SSIS that is inserting and updating, except that it seems to be updating 250+ rows each time it runs, whether an update was made to the source or not. Insert works correctly. But it only works when I "ignore error" on the conditional split, otherwise the split " evaluated to NULL, but the "Conditional Split" requires a Boolean results " error shows up. Any idea on how I can fix this? My conditional split looks like this:

```
UPDATE = [Copy of ORDER_TYPE] != ORDER_TYPE || [Copy of WEEK] != WEEK || [Copy of GOAL] != GOAL || [Copy of WEEK_START] != WEEK_START || [Copy of WEEK_END] != WEEK_END || [Copy of DIVISION_DESC] != DIVISION_DESC || [Copy of SUB_ORDER_TYPE] != SUB_ORDER_TYPE
INSERT = ISNULL(ID) || ISNULL(WEEK) || ORDER_TYPE == ""
```

I followed [this](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/insert-update-data-using-merge-join-ssis.php) tutorial.

Comment: In a situation like this, it's impossible for us to debug what is happening as we don't have access to your data, your package and the results of the above boolean conditions. What I do, when faced with a problem like this, is to add one, possibly two, Derived Column task before the Conditional Split. Add a column `IsInsert` and `IsUpdate` and the use the above expressions. Now connect your derived column to the Conditional Split and replace the two expressions to just use our derived columns. Add a data viewer immediately before the split and you can verify whether your logic is sound

Comment: Given the length of your UPDATE expression, I would break that into individual columns evaluations in a derived column before derived column I described above. Here, you'll break out each column change check i.e. Changed_ORDER_TYPE `[Copy of ORDER_TYPE] != ORDER_TYPE`  That then simplifies the IsUpdate logic to `Changed_ORDER_TYPE || Changed_WEEK...`  Now that data viewer will show you the exact condition that is resulting in the Change to be erroneously flagged. Based on your "ignore error" comment, I assume you have a condition with NULL comparison that is not covered by the referenced link.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks

Comment: that worked. The data viewer showed that one of my input columns was converting as float, while the table datatype was int, so the values with decimals are different than those in the table, as they get converted as int. fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed. I added my comments in as an answer so *I* have a reference of how I troubleshoot but you're most welcome to add your own answer since you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this, it's impossible for us to debug what is happening as we don't have access to your data, your package and the results of the above boolean conditions.
What I do, when faced with a problem like this, is to add one, possibly two, Derived Column task before the Conditional Split. The first I'd called `DER Action Flags` as we'll generate the boolean conditions for the action we should take.

Add a column `IsInsert` and `IsUpdate` and the use the above expressions. Now connect your derived column to the Conditional Split and replace the two expressions to just use our new derived columns. Add a data viewer immediately before the split and you can verify whether your logic is sound.

Given the length of your UPDATE expression, I would break that into individual column evaluations in a derived column before `DER Action Flags` I described above. Call it something like `DER Compute Changed Flags` to indicate we're computing the whether the column has changed.

In this Derived Column component, you'll break out each column change check i.e.

- Changed_ORDER_TYPE `[Copy of ORDER_TYPE] != ORDER_TYPE`
- Changed_WEEK `[Copy of WEEK] != WEEK`

That then simplifies the `IsUpdate` logic to `Changed_ORDER_TYPE || Changed_WEEK...`

Now that data viewer will show you the *exact* condition that is resulting in the Change to be erroneously flagged. That distills the problem down to these two inputs and this expression are not evaluating as expected (and that is something we can figure out)

Based on your "ignore error" comment, I assume you have a condition with NULL comparison that might not be covered by the referenced link.

And since this is a series of Comments converted to an answer,

> That worked. The data viewer showed that one of my input columns was converting as float, while the table datatype was int, so the values with decimals are different than those in the table, as they get converted as int. fixed.

Future readers, verify your data types (double click the connector lines out of a component and select MetaData) a consistent as data conversion rules might surprise you in unexpected ways.